# pd.Series.str.upper function under the df.apply() is showing me the Error. On the other hand pd.Series.min is running perfectly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, series, python-applymap

When I use **df.apply(pd.Series.str.upper)** shows me an error -

Although **df.apply(pd.Series.min)** is running absolutely fine! and **df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper())** is running fine too.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     "Name":[
         "Harry","Sam", "Jack"], "Gender": ["M","M","F"]})


df.apply(pd.Series.str.lower)
```

```
Error - Series' object has no attribute '_inferred_dtype'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you apply `pd.Series.str` its converting each row to `String Series` type hence `lower` method would not work unless you apply individually like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     "Name":[
         "Harry","Sam", "Jack"], "Gender": ["M","M","F"]
    }
)
df.apply(pd.Series.str) # Check output in below image
```

[image: Appliying_Series_Str]

Its clear if you want to apply `lower` you have to iteratively apply at every instance hence 'lambda' would be useful

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adapt your `upper()` approach, it should give you the expected result:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
```